# passing parameters using vent.js. How can I read that data in the next page-view that will load after the event is triggered?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have this view

```
define(['marionette', 'tpl!templates/profiles/_profile_item.html','vent'], function(Marionette, template,vent) {

  var ProfileItemView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({ 
    template: template,

    events: {
        "click button": function() {
            // alert(this.model.get('name') + " was clicked!");

        if(this.model.get('name')=='Guest')
          vent.trigger('navigate','player');
        else if(this.model.get('name')=='Create profile')
          vent.trigger('navigate','createProfile');
        else
          vent.trigger('navigate','loginProfile',{
                      name: this.model.get('name')
                      });

        }
    }

  });

  return ProfileItemView;

});
```

inside the else I trigger navigate and pass some data. My question is how can I read that data in the next page-view that will load after the event is triggered?

Answer (score 1):

```
    vent.on('navigate', this.someFunction);

    someFunction:function(e){
        // e your data
    }
```